# Combine Alt and AltGr keys

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, keyboard-layout

On macOS, there is no distinction made between Alt and AltGr, both keys are labelled "option" and used for both hotkeys and inserting special characters like @€£‰¶÷[]≠.

That is, I can use either one of the "option" keys to insert symbols (e.g. option-1 for ) and I can also use either one of the "option" keys for keyboard shortcuts (e.g. command-option-F).

I use the same keyboard for Linux, but left option is mapped to Alt (for keyboard shortcuts) and right option is mapped to AltGr (for inserting symbols). How do I change it so that both keys can be used for both purposes?

I have a fresh install of whatever the latest version of GNOME Fedora is at the moment

Comment: Presumably the re-labelling of the keys is not part of the question, as that involves either replacement key caps or a small paintbrush and some paint.  But what does "in Linux" constitute?  In a kernel virtual terminal?  In a X11 terminal emulator application?  In all X11 applications?  And how, if terminals are involved, are you envisaging the same key chord being _both_ an accelerator key _and_ a non-Latin1 character?  And what Linux distribution, with its particular way of configuring things, would be involved?

Comment: Hi! I'm not sure what you're asking for, when you say "similar effect". You brought up an example, which doesn't make sense (the "option" key is the "option" key, not "Alt", nor "AltGr") in itself much. Can you, instead of making a comparison, actually describe what you want to achieve, exactly. Something like: "*I want to enter characters like {character you want to enter} by pressing {what you want to press, in which order} while using {what you want to use, eg. "my browser on Gnome on wayland"}.*" That would actually make your question much easier to answer :)